# CSS is slowing down the page rendering

Tags: html, dom, css

We have a page where use can browse 2000 profiles max, we add 20 profiles as user scroll to bottom of page. After 500 elements the adding of profiles get slower and after 1000 its very difficult to scroll down. 
 We first thought that it was result of too many DOM objects but after debugging it turns out that `CSS` was the actual problem, if we remove the CSS from page scrolling become very smooth till the 2000 profiles. Can any one tell me why CSS is doing this? and how we can improve it to show 2000 profiles.

Our profile contains one image only and no text.

**CSS** is as below.

```
.profileCard {
  width: 25rem;
  height: 10rem;
  float: left;
}
.profileCard .imageHolder {
  width: 9.9rem;
  height: 9.9rem;
  float: left;
}
.profileCard .imageHolderSecondary {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.profileCard .imageHolderSecondaryTwo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageCard .profileCard {
   width: 18.75rem;
   height: 18.75rem;
   background-color: white;
}
.imageCard .profileCard .imageHolder {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
.imageCard .profileCard .imageHolder .profileImage {
   min-width: 18.75rem;
   min-height: 18.75rem;
 }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="profileCard">
  <div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="imageHolderSecondary">
      <div class="imageHolderSecondaryTwo"> 
        <div class="profileImageContainer"> 
          <img id="imageUrl" class="profileImage" src="http://graph.facebook.com/xyz/picture?type=large" title="undefined"></img> 
        </div> 
       </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/ test case?

Comment: I was going to say exactly the same thing. REM is CSS3. I would investigate there.

Comment: I have also tried em, result is still same.
We use rem as this is one of the part of our web page. Since, within the page, font size is changing at different levels, I want to control the sizing of different components globally using rem. If I use em, controlling components globally will be a headache.

Comment: @thirtydot can you guide how to make the test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of layout are you aiming for because the floating seems excessive especially with no sign of clearing. The browser will likely be having a nightmare dealing with all those float positioning calculations.

EDIT: Not quite the same situation but it seems someone else has had a similar webkit related problem. I've no idea what QT is but it seems like a very similar stuttery scroll bar problem. https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTWEBKIT-122

Comment: We are targeting an image grid view.

Comment: Hmm, well maybe switch from floating to inline-block, most browsers support it now anyway. In any case, for testing how about just removing floating and see what it does?

Comment: floating left is the problem, removing it fixed the problem. Thankssss

Comment: I'd basically set .profileCard to display: inline-block; Then because facebook profile images are a fixed size specify the width explicitly. If you don't know the size of the image I'd probably use jQuery to catch the image load the set it once explicitly once the image has loaded, setting it once and leaving it will be far less intensive than recalculating. If that's no help post a wire layout and I'll figure out the css

Answer (score 2):

Change your usage of REM to EM, and you should be fine. Considering REM is a CSS3 feature, it isn't as widely supported, and definitely not as widely optimized.

[This article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) provides a good explanation of how to effectively use EMs, and it discusses REMs too.

Comment: Tried em still same result :(

Comment: In the HTML you provided, you have one too many `</div>` tags. Is that relevant?

Comment: Can you provide an example that we can access and tinker with? Maybe a static HTML page with all 2000 entries, or similar?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting problem. After looking at your code, I think you could speed it up if you set explicit sizes for your 100% elements. I believe the browser has to constantly re-parse the dom to figure out the 100% size every time you load one of those elements. It is an easy test to try a static size to see if this is the right direction.